# Lambda Expression

Tags: python, lambda

Found this on python documentation.
How is this working exactly ?

```
pairs = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1])
print pairs
```

I'm unable to understand how `key=lambda pair:pair[1]`is working.

What is `pair` here? From where the `pair` is fetching the value because the name of the original list is `pairs`?

Comment: What don't you understand in that?

Comment: it sorts with second item in the tuple see the reult

Comment: If you see the result of `sort`, you would see that the items are sorted based on 2nd element of each item(tuple) in the list.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I don't understand from where the value in `pair` is getting from the original list `pairs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lambda pair:pair[1]
```

is same as

```
def f(pair): return pair[1]
```